# Vて vs Vてから vs Vたうえで

Tags: jlpt

There is a question in JLPT Prep book Kanzen Master N2 that confuses me:

> 一緒に料理を（　）食べませんか。
>   a. 作って 　b.作ってから 　c.作った上で

Vた上で suggests a cause/effect relationship so c is obviously wrong.

a is right but I want to know why b is wrong? 

It's grammatically wrong or is there a problem with the meaning in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about how the 一緒に part is involved. If you made it `b`, the 一緒に would only apply to the first part leaving 食べませんか by itself and making it not clear that that part is also supposed to be 一緒に.

Answer (score 6):

AしてBしませんか sounds to me like "Let's do A and B", whereas AしてからBしませんか sounds to me like "How about doing A before doing B?" 

Compare:

> 映画に行って食事しませんか。・・・asking out to the movies and dinner
>   映画に行ってから食事しませんか。・・・asking out to the movies (going out to dinner has been agreed). OR, suggesting going to the movies BEFORE dinner, rather than AFTER.

Likewise,

> 一緒に料理を作って食べませんか。・・・Both cooking and eating are suggested.
>   一緒に料理を作ってから食べませんか。・・・sounds strange because you can't just eat without cooking or eat before you cook.